# No wiring diagram on motor!

Tags: motor

I have no idea where to connect my power leads to this electrical block on my saw motor, its a 220v single phase, the white wires are the capacitor.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvvkWC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Disconnect the wire at 5 and confirm with a multimeter that one coil (MAIN) is terminated at 1 and 4.
- While 5 is disconnected check for continuity between it and 3.
- If wiring is as shown then apply power directly to the MAIN coil on 1 and 4 (or 2 and 5).

The capacitor causes a small phase-shift in the current in the START winding relative to the MAIN winding so that a definite starting torque and direction is produced.

(The wires on 4 and 5 may be swapped. You should be able to figure this out. Either way, apply mains to 1 and 4, etc.)